# Android Layout priority

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to divide a screen into 2 sections. The above section is a map widget. Below is an other layout filled with widgets. The problem is that the map widget fills the whole screen. How can I make the layout below the map push te map up?

I'm guessing it could be solved by giving the map widget a height, but that's not very flexible.

My attemp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:apiKey="my api key" />





    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_menu" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mapview"
        android:background="@drawable/locatie_background" >


        <Button android:id="@+id/firstButtonId" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/action_ready" 
            />

    </RelativeLayout >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this : android:layout_weight="1" in RelativeLayout. I think it will solve your problem

Comment: @Kartik No it won't. `layout_weight` is ignored by `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried to change to parent layout to linearLayout so I can assign a weight to the second relative layout. But it's giving the same result

Comment: Why don't you use `LinearLayout`? And how much do you want to push the map up?

Comment: as much as nessasiery. I want the bottom section's height to be high enough to show it's content (a few buttons and an image)

Comment: So you don't want the screen to be divided equally?

Comment: Nope, I want the topscreen's height to be scaled looking at the bottom content (bottom get's priority).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of RelativeLayout use LinearLayout like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_menu1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my api key" />
</LinearLayout >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_menu" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button android:id="@+id/firstButtonId" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="action_ready" 
        />

</LinearLayout >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Technically it is correct but the unnecessary second `LinearLayout` was worth a -1.

Comment: Checkout my answer and you'll see the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Go with a `LinearLayout`, set the `layout_height` of both children to `wrap_content` and set the `layout_weight` of both to `1`.

This would divide the screens height equally:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my api key" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_menu" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/mapview"
        android:background="@drawable/locatie_background">
        <Button android:id="@+id/firstButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action_ready" />
    </RelativeLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```

You can work with `layout_weight` as if they would be percent values like here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my api key" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_menu" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_below="@id/mapview"
        android:background="@drawable/locatie_background">
        <Button android:id="@+id/firstButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action_ready" />
    </RelativeLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I trie this I get Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value '0').

Comment: I have another question concerning this. I tried putting 10 buttons in the second layout instead of 1 but it seems that the layout cannot be stredged more then the height of it's background. Is this normal?

Comment: Well if you have so many options one could select then I'd go with a `Spinner`.

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">



<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:apiKey="my api key" />





<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_menu" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mapview"
    android:background="@drawable/locatie_background" >


    <Button android:id="@+id/firstButtonId" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/action_ready" 
        />

</RelativeLayout >

</LinearLayout>
```